# how to mail value of form not the screenshot of contact.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to send mail from my contact form. But I am getting error.

**contact.blade.php is:**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ URL('send') }}">
  {{csrf_field()}}
    <table align="center" width="400">
   <tr>
     <td><strong>Full Name</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" required="required" /></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
      <td><strong>Contact No.</strong></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="mobno" required="required" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td><strong>Email ID</strong></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" required="required" /></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Message</strong></td>
        <td><textarea name="msg" cols="30" rows="3" required="required"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
           <td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
     </form>
```

**web.php is:**

```
Route::POST('send', 'ContactController@send');
```

**ContactController.php is:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\officeholder;
use App\Mail\SendMail;
use Mail;

class ContactController extends Controller
{

public function send()
{
    Mail::send(new SendMail());
}
}
```

**I have created SendMail.php using

> php artisan make:mail SendMail

by my cmd and then App\Mail\SendMail.php is created.**

**SendMail.php is:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Http\request;

class SendMail extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;


public function __construct()
{
    //
}


public function build(Request $request)
{
    return $this->view('contact',['msg'=>$request->msg])->to('mymail@gmail.com');
}
}
```

**But screenshot of my contact.blade.php is sending to my mail, not the value of form and it also not redirect on contact page.**

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: make another blade template and use that in your Mailable, you're sending the html page you want the frontend to use in the mail

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Mail is sending. I need to send mail with form input value. Now i am getting screenshot of contact.blade.php in my mail box.

Comment: make a separate blade file and include that blade in view method

Comment: Thnks Leentje, Its working. But how to redirect on contact.blade.php

Comment: Thnks  Shaielndra Gupta, Its working. But how to redirect on contact.blade.php

Answer (score 2):

Pass the data in the contructor

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{

public function send()
{
    Mail::send(new SendMail(request()));
    redirect()->to('url');
}
}
```

And in your Mail

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Http\request;

class SendMail extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;
private $request;

public function __construct( Request $request )
{
     $this->request =  $request;
}


public function build()
{
    return $this->view('contact',['msg'=>$this->request->msg])->to('mymail@gmail.com');
}
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have make a separate blade file and include that blade in view method. Now its working

Comment: But it is not redirecting on contact.blade.php after mail sending

Comment: @cloudsoft ```redirect()->to('url')```

Comment: return $this->view('contact',['msg'=>$this->request->msg])->to('mymail@gmail.com')->redirect()->to('url');

Comment: LInk above comment?

Comment: @cloudsoft you only redirect from controller

Comment: return redirect('contact'); Now redirect